# Generating static HTML files with Handlebars js

Tags: html, handlebars.js

How would I use handlebars to pre-compile a template to html and save the resulting HTML as a static HTML file, is it possible to do this?  Based on what I've been reading it isn't but I was hoping maybe there is a Grunt task or something I missed...

Comment: You could visit the page and have javascript send the page's html to the server in an ajax request and then have the server save it to a file. If you want something more automated, you could use phantomjs, a headless browser, to automatically create/update files on a set schedule. That is a standard approach to creating SEO snapshots of ajax sites. If this is the answer you're looking for, I'll post it. :)

Comment: I'm thinking this is more of a build process/pre-deploy task, like I have some data, I have some templates, I want to compile them together into one static HTML file and then deploy the HTML.

Comment: Right, and since javascript does the compiling and you want the process to be automated, you would use phantomJS to "visit" those pages for you and export the compiled html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This that does what I was looking for
https://github.com/patrickkettner/grunt-compile-handlebars

Comment: Very useful because this is exactly what I was looking for :-) I have a dynamic website but I think compiling templates once every 15 minutes into static files would work well. Keeping the actual webserver dumb. Certainly gone give it a try.